# How to add overlay color on the BitmapDescriptor for Android project in Xamarin Forms Maps

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So, I implemented custom renderer for Android regarding XF Maps, everything is ok, and now I want to add overlay for my pin.

```
protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
{
      CustomPin customPin = (CustomPin)pin;
      var marker = new MarkerOptions();
      marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
      marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
      marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
      marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
           
      return marker;
}
```

How to add an overlay color on pin image? for example `Color.FromHex("#34ee16")`

Comment: So, you want to color your pin?

Comment: @Stefan exactly. Just to put color overlay above my image that represents the pin.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the pin color ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT yes. I saw there is an option to put Overlay over Bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to set the pin color in Xamarin.Forms.Maps.But you could do like below to change the color of your custom pin.

```
protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
 {
    CustomPin customPin = (CustomPin)pin;
    var marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
    marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
    marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
    Color color = Color.FromHex("#34ee16");
    float hue = color.ToAndroid().GetHue() % 360.0f;
    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(hue));      
    return marker;
 }
```